# Firefox 8 still doesn't support multiline titles or alt-text ("tooltips")?

Tags: html, firefox, multiline, tooltip

Despite this documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-title

and HTML5 having a spec for multiline

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#the-title-attribute

I cannot reproduce that behavior in Firefox 8.

Just wanted to make sure I am not missing something.

All other modern browsers support multiline except Firefox? Seriously?

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried with Chrome and Firefox 8.0 and seen the same behaviour - Firefox ignores the newlines, Chrome does not.

This bug report seems to be relevant:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=358452

> Many web authors make use of the MSIE behavior that translates newlines in title attributes into line breaks in the resulting tooltip.  This has led to frequent requests for Mozilla to do the same thing...
>
> Emulating MSIE's behavior is not ideal: it can easily lead to accidental line breaks if the HTML source is word-wrapped, and it is not compatible with web standards...
>
> However, it could be consistent with the spec to allow character entities such as 
>  to yield tooltip line breaks by delaying entity replacement until after explicit CRs and tabs have been replaced by spaces.

Comment: HTML5 spec says you can also use &#10; instead of \n but that method also doesn't work in Firefox but works in Chrome/Safari/IE8